# How can I pull all the last values from an associative array's keys in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a structure like:

```
$array = [
    'item-1' => [ 'item-child-1', 'item-child-2' ]
    'item-2' => [ 'item-child-1', 'item-child-2' , 'item-child-3']
    'item-3' => [ 'item-child-1' ]
];
```

Where I would like to return each `item-X`'s last values. In my case, a new array should be created:

```
$new_array = [
    'item-1' => 'item-child-2',
    'item-2' => 'item-child-3',
    'item-3' => 'item-child-1'
]
```

How can I achieve this without entering a loop nightmare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `foreach` with `end()` will do the trick for you.

```
<?php

$array = [
    'item-1' => [ 'item-child-1', 'item-child-2' ],
    'item-2' => [ 'item-child-1', 'item-child-2' , 'item-child-3'],
    'item-3' => [ 'item-child-1' ]
];

$expected = [];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $expected[$k]=end($v);
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($expected);
print '</pre>';
```

**DEMO** https://3v4l.org/suISW

**OR** using `foreach()` and  `count()`

```
$expected = [];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $expected[$k]=$v[count($v)-1];
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/nt3oM

**OR** Pretty neat with `array_map()`

```
$output = array_map(function ($arr) {return end($arr);}, $array);
```

**DEMO** https://3v4l.org/2Zl0l

Comment: Ah, for sure, but isn't there an one-liner for this? Native to PHP? I'm working in a semi-complex system where the logic is already complex / hard to read.

Comment: @coolpasta I've **Edited** my answer with one liner solution. Have a look again